# CGImage not being rotated when given an iOS landscape photo

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

What part of this line of code is preventing the image from being rotated the right way? When I take a picture with my iOS device in landscape orientation, the resulting UIImage isn't rotated right side up...

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage, scale: 0.2, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Up), 0.1)
```

Comment: didnt understand ur question ,the code works properly.Default landscape images are `UIImageOrientation.Up` try changing orientation u will get some clue

Comment: For some reason, images that I've taken in landscape orientation aren't being presented "right-side up" as my images taken in portrait orientation are. Instead, they're being presented 90 degrees rotated.

Comment: are u taking image from imagepicker?

Comment: Yes, from imagepicker

Answer (score 0):

Below i have  used  the code of selecting image form picker and rotated in 4 direction.The image i choose was of default landscape from iphone simulator i.e **UP**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[picker removeFromParentViewController];      
UIImage *upimage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] CGImage] scale:0.2 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];

crop.adjustedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(upimage, 0.2)];


[self presentViewController:crop animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**LEFT**

[image]

**DOWN**

[image]

**RIGHT**

[image]

**UP**

[image]

Comment: If I use a photo taken in landscape orientation, it's not presented right-side up despite my use of UIOrientationUp. It's presented as if I used UIOrientationLeft.